# make a question sentence with adjective '' long ''

Tags: adjectives

As far as i know it is correct to say:

> A two-meter-long fossilized turtle discovered .

When we make this sentence structure into question sentence , can i say :

> How- many -meter -long fossilized turtle  was discovered ?

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct.  Did you leave out a **was**?  "A two-meter-long fossilized turtle **was** discovered."

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in standard English (though some people, particularly maths and science geeks, will write "a how-many-metre-long turtle").

In standard English, it has to be recast: "How many metres long was the fossilized turtle that was discovered?"

Answer (score 1):

When making a statement it is useful, perhaps essential to state the units

> "A three-metre-long turtle"

When asking a question you don't need to state the units

> How long was the turtle?

It is up to the person who answers to give the units.

If you want to specify units, you may do so:

> How long was the turtle, in metres?